Power Automate condition for built in approval function in MS Lists
Would like to setup a condition (or a set of conditions) in Power Automate for different stages of the integrated approval function in MS Lists. Ie one outcome for approved, rejected, requested, not submitted etc. (see screenshot for column statuses)
Column Status
the intended workflow would be the integrated form in ms lists is filled in by a user and then an email is sent to the user who created the item via a form as confirmation of their submission
Another senior user would then create three approvals on the ms list itself (three different approvers).
Approvals would be done via teams approvals app by the three approvers. Once all three approve, then an approved email is sent to all approvers and user who filled form. If even one rejection happens, a rejection email is sent to all approvers and user who filled form.
I’ve already tried creating a condition in power automate for each possible outcome but can’t find the right dynamic content from the ms list to link to (see screenshot for attempt at flow)
Condition for Power Automate
Your help would be much appreciated!
